# Looking for specific Javascript library / jQuery plugin for creative coding

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, processing, p5.js

I'm new here! I'm going crazy about this thing so I decided to ask to your beautiful community.

A few months ago I was on the internet, possibly reading about Processing and other creative coding environments. Then I came by this beautiful ¿home page? which had a full viewport pattern of **stick figures** coloured **pink** and / or **violet**. You could drag and drop the stick figures and they would fly from their place, or at least, that's what I can remember.

Bad news is, I loved this JS library or whatever it was, but I **didn't save it into my bookmarks**. So I lost it :'( and of course I don't remember its name. I've been looking like crazy, came by a lot of interesting JS libraries with similar functionality (obvs p5.js, d3.js, paper.js, sketch.js, particles.js, snap.svg, mo.js..... goes on) but I didn't find the one with the stick figures you could fool around with. Damn, I really liked it :(

So does anyone have any clue what I'm talking about?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [P5.js](https://p5js.org/). The homepage has been showcasing art by various [diverse artists](http://diversity.p5js.org/). A few months ago it was stick-figure super-women who would fly around. They've since changed it to a new project, which is why you didn't see it when you visited the page again.

[Here](https://twitter.com/p5xjs/status/860554587060568064) is a tweet from the offical P5.js account that mentions the Superwoman project. (Also includes a video.)

The Superwoman project was made by [Qianqian Ye](http://www.qianqian-ye.com/), and [here](http://www.qianqian-ye.com/superwoman.html) is a page that describes it in more detail.

By the way, questions like this asking about off-site resources are very off-topic for Stack Overflow. I remembered exactly what you were talking about so I figured I'd answer it, but usually questions like these are closed.

Comment: yes!!! that was totally it!! I knew inside me it was p5 hahaha. Here there's a link to a functional demo of the project: http://www.qianqian-ye.com/Everyday/Day44/ thank you!!!

Comment: I know what you mean, this was 100% random, I was only having a shot. Figured someone in creative coding field could help me out. Thanks again :)